# Accessing stackoverflow API with jsonp gives unexpected result

Tags: ajax, api, jsonp

I am trying to access the Stackoverflow API with jsonp as datatype by doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/tags/php/top-answerers/month',
          dataType: 'jsonp',
        });
      });
```

And once I reload, I get the following in the console:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It looks like the API doesn't support JSONP, it's returning ordinary JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now the application is returning Content-Type: `application/json`.

You can fix this by overriding the callback function name to `jsonp` which will tell the server to return Content-Type: `application/javascript` instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/tags/php/top-answerers/month',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.top_users.length + ' users retrieved.');
        }
    });
});
```

Info on jsonp ajax setting:

> **jsonpString**
>
> Override the callback function name in a jsonp request. This value
>   will be used instead of 'callback' in the 'callback=?' part of the
>   query string in the url. So {jsonp:'onJSONPLoad'} would result in
>   'onJSONPLoad=?' passed to the server. As of jQuery 1.5, setting the
>   jsonp option to false prevents jQuery from adding the "?callback"
>   string to the URL or attempting to use "=?" for transformation. In
>   this case, you should also explicitly set the jsonpCallback setting.
>   For example, { jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: "callbackName" }

Answer (score 0):

From https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

> All API responses are JSON, we do support JSONP with the callback query parameter. Every response in the API is returned in a common "wrapper" object, for easier and more consistent parsing.

So you should use `dataType: 'json'` rather than `jsonp`.

You should also upgrade to the 2.1 API, the 1.x API has been deprecated for 6 months.

Comment: using 'json' instead gives: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/tags/php/top-answerers/month. Origin http://localhost:26562 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`